# Online repository for family memorabilia

Tags: file-management, data

I want to identify suitable software to establish an on-line repository for multiple family members to load and store family memorabilia.  The memorabilia may be in the format of images, text, sound files, perhaps limited video etc.  The repository should be secure, searchable, expandable and, preferably, open-source.  I envisage initially about 12 users who would be subject to privileges granted by an administrator.

Comment: I'm not sure.  I asked this question to my friend (a computer professional) and he suggested that I pose the question here.  If there are many suitable cloud storage software providers that can achieve this, I'd be grateful for your recommendation of a few.  Thanks

Comment: Agreed. OP might as well use one of the many free online office/project/software development suites. Or, if slightly tech savvy, set up a community using Drupal  and configure it appropriately. See https://groups.drupal.org/node/428728  and  https://www.drupal.org/project/family  and https://groups.drupal.org/genealogy

Comment: Question needs some improvement as well – missing things like a) platform b) availability (public, local), c) privacy protection, d) target audience (e.g. "grandma and the baby must be able to deal with it"), e) maybe something more I didn't see on a "quick glance". Mind [edit]ing your question and improve it? That would certainly enhance your chances for good answers, as a.o. the one or other detail might trigger ideas :)